# Let $p : K \rightarrow L$ be a non-zero homomorphism, where $K$ and $ L$ are fields. Show that $p$ is a monomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Textbook Solution: Since $\ker \varphi$ is an ideal of $K$, it follows from previous excerise that $\ker \varphi = \{0\}$. Hence $\forall a,b \in K$,
$$ \varphi(a)=\varphi(b) \Rightarrow a-b \in \ker\varphi = \{0\} \Rightarrow a = b$$

I am really having a problem understanding this proof. Can someone explain it, or provide me an alternative proof? thank you for your time.

Comment: Skipping the 'previous exercise' such that you actually see why. If $x\neq y$ and $p(x)=p(y)$, i.e. if it is not injective, then $p(x-y)=p(x)-p(y)=0$. It follows that for all $z\in K$ we have $p(z)=p((x-y)(x-y)^{-1}z)=p(x-y)p((x-y)^{-1}z)=0$.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. I am reading Fields and Galois Theory. Why I am confused is because invective, means that every element in $K$ must map to an element in $L$. How does showing this equality show that the mapping is one-to-one?

Comment: What I proved was that if it is not injective then it is constant equal to zero. The counterpositive of that gives that if it is not constant equal to zero, then it should be injective.

Comment: I actually did and posted the answer below. Try to make a better effort on reading the page content before commenting on peoples posts telling them to make an effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that might find this question helpful later on, heres my solution

Recall that if $\varphi$ is one to one then $\varphi$ is a monomorphism. Recall that by defnition of one to one, every element in $K$ must be mapped to exactly one element in $L$. Recall that a field is a field iff the only ideals are $\{0\}$ and the field itself. This means that the kernal of $\varphi$ is $\{0\}$. Hence $\forall a,b \in K$, 
$$\varphi(a) = \varphi(b) \Rightarrow 0 = \varphi(a)-\varphi(b) \Rightarrow a-b = 0 \Rightarrow a-b\in \ker\varphi$$
This means that $a = b$. Hence $\varphi$ is one to one since no two elements of $K$ map to the same element in $L$.

Comment: You should say why the kernel is not the entire field.

Comment: Good point I will try to work on that. Its a known theorem in the textbook I am using but its always good to verify

Comment: Hint: it's in the definition of a homomorphism of fields!